# How can I store azure.eventhub.common.Offset in Python?

Tags: python, azure, serialization, offset, azure-eventhub

According to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#stream-offsets) for Azure event hubs, it is the consumer's responsibility to manage offsets. Quoting:

> Consumers are responsible for storing their own offset values outside
>   of the Event Hubs service.

But looking at the [API doc for event hub Offset class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-eventhub/azure.eventhub.common.offset?view=azure-python), it is immediately obvious that it offers no way to be serialized or otherwise stored.

So my question is: **how would I go about storing event hub Offsets?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please carefully refer to the source code of [`common.py`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/blob/master/azure/eventhub/common.py) of GitHub repo [`Azure/azure-event-hubs-python`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python) and the [`Offset`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/blob/master/azure/eventhub/common.py#L253) class is defined at the line 253 as below.

```
class Offset(object):
    """
    The offset (position or timestamp) where a receiver starts. Examples:
    Beginning of the event stream:
      >>> offset = Offset("-1")
    End of the event stream:
      >>> offset = Offset("@latest")
    Events after the specified offset:
      >>> offset = Offset("12345")
    Events from the specified offset:
      >>> offset = Offset("12345", True)
    Events after a datetime:
      >>> offset = Offset(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    Events after a specific sequence number:
      >>> offset = Offset(1506968696002)
    """

    def __init__(self, value, inclusive=False):
        """
        Initialize Offset.
        :param value: The offset value.
        :type value: ~datetime.datetime or int or str
        :param inclusive: Whether to include the supplied value as the start point.
        :type inclusive: bool
        """
        self.value = value
        self.inclusive = inclusive

    def selector(self):
        """
        Creates a selector expression of the offset.
        :rtype: bytes
        """
        operator = ">=" if self.inclusive else ">"
        if isinstance(self.value, datetime.datetime):
            timestamp = (calendar.timegm(self.value.utctimetuple()) * 1000) + (self.value.microsecond/1000)
            return ("amqp.annotation.x-opt-enqueued-time {} '{}'".format(operator, int(timestamp))).encode('utf-8')
        if isinstance(self.value, six.integer_types):
            return ("amqp.annotation.x-opt-sequence-number {} '{}'".format(operator, self.value)).encode('utf-8')
        return ("amqp.annotation.x-opt-offset {} '{}'".format(operator, self.value)).encode('utf-8')
```

According to the source code of `Offset` class, it's just a normal Python class with two properties `value` and `inclusive`. You can simply store the values of its properties as json string or others, or just extract these values, as my sample code below.

```
from azure.eventhub.common import Offset
offset = Offset("-1")
print(offset.value, offset.inclusive)
# -1 False
print(offset.__dict__)
# {'value': '-1', 'inclusive': False}
import json
offset_json = json.dumps(offset.__dict__)
# '{"value": "-1", "inclusive": false}'
```

Note: In the future, GitHub repo [`Azure/azure-event-hubs-python`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python) will completed move to GitHub repo [`Azure/azure-sdk-for-python`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python), the changes for `Offset` class is renamed as [`EventPosition`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhubs/azure/eventhub/common.py#L381) class with the same properties `value` and `inclusive`.